# When does map method initiate in laravel service provider?

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I'm trying to dig deeper into laravel framework, this time I'm developing a big application so I decided to do it in a modular way. Currently i'm using [Laravel Modules](https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules) package which provides Service providers for my own modules. I realise that it acts as a gateway to register the views, routes, etc.

However I can't really find when do the **map** function is called in laravel lifecycle. I tried to go to the `parent::boot();` function but it does not initiate the method as well.

```
    public function map()
    {
        $this->mapApiRoutes();

        $this->mapWebRoutes();
    }
```

I want to make sure that when I develop my modules, the routes are registered in my app. However I can't even find the lifecycle in the main app, can anyone help?

Comment: Don't know much about Laravel, but did some digging anyway. I'm guessing you're referring to the `RouteServiceProvider`. Seems that the [Boot](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/providers#the-boot-method) part of that provider is [there](https://github.com/guiwoda/laravel-framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Support/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L26), and calls [this](https://github.com/guiwoda/laravel-framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Support/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L71) which in turn calls that method you posted. Hope that helps.

Comment: wow how can I not check the loadRoutes... thanks for the help, you can post it as answer that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That method is part of the [Route Service Provider](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Foundation/Support/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.html).

Any Service Provider has a [Boot method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/providers#the-boot-method):

> This method is called after all other service providers have been
>   registered.

In the case of the Route Service Provider, the `boot()` implementation can be viewed [here](https://github.com/guiwoda/laravel-framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Support/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L26).  It proceeds to call an internal [`loadRoutes` method](https://github.com/guiwoda/laravel-framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Support/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L71) which in turn calls the method you're referring to.